# rails - activerecord SELECT TOP 1 field_name * FROM table_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a sql like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 field_name * FROM table_name
```

and I want to covert it into activerecord in rails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code doesn't do the job?

```
YourModel.select(:field_name).first
```

or

```
YourModel.select(:field_name).order('id desc').first
```

Comment: You could also use `YourModel.select(:field_name).limit(1)`, but that doesn't really matter here, since the `first` method, when used on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` (as in this case), will actually do `limit(1).to_a`

Comment: Yes, limit(1) is better than first.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `limit(1)` or `first`:

```
Model.select(:field_name).limit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

### pick (Rails 6+)

Since Rails 6, you can use the following:

```rb
YourModel.order(id: :desc).pick(:field_name)
```

[pick](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pick) is even more efficient than

```rb
YourModel.select(:field_name).order('id desc').first
```

since, it will only load the actual value, not the entire record object.

For more details, please, follow this [link to docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pick).

Also, there is a [reference to the corresponding PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/31941).